# Admin Plugins For Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a good admin plugin/gem for a Rails 3 application. I have tested rails_admin and it seems very good. Has anybody used any other plugins for Rails 3.0?

Also has anybody had any issues with rails_admin?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of options, at the moment. Check all of them out here.

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces.html

I have heard both admin_data and typus are good.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Typus, but their wiki has 30 pages: https://github.com/fesplugas/typus/wiki

Answer (score 2):

Using Rails Admin too. Never had a problem.